# How do I find out how to fill the missing AES type parameter in AesGcm<Aes, NonceSize, TagSize = U16>?

Tags: generics, rust, encryption, aes, type-parameter

I'm using AES256-GCM, but with 12-byte tags for compatibility reasons.

Therefore I need to use the generic [AesGcm](https://docs.rs/aes-gcm/latest/aes_gcm/struct.AesGcm.html)

> Struct aes_gcm::AesGcm source ·
>
> pub struct AesGcm<Aes, NonceSize, TagSize = U16>where
> TagSize: TagSize,{ /* private fields */ }
>
> AES-GCM: generic over an underlying AES implementation and nonce size.
>
> This type is generic to support substituting alternative AES
> implementations (e.g. embedded hardware implementations)
>
> It is NOT intended to be instantiated with any block cipher besides
> AES! Doing so runs the risk of unintended cryptographic properties!
>
> The NonceSize generic parameter can be used to instantiate AES-GCM
> with other nonce sizes, however it’s recommended to use it with
> typenum::U12, the default of 96-bits.
>
> The TagSize generic parameter can be used to instantiate AES-GCM with
> other authorization tag sizes, however it’s recommended to use it with
> typenum::U16, the default of 128-bits.
>
> If in doubt, use the built-in Aes128Gcm and Aes256Gcm type aliases.

rather than [Aes256Gcm](https://docs.rs/aes-gcm/latest/aes_gcm/struct.AesGcm.html).

My error is:

```
error[E0412]: cannot find type `Aes` in this scope
   --> common/src/main.rs:108:39
    |
108 |         let cipher = <aes_gcm::AesGcm<Aes, aes_gcm::aead::consts::U12, aes_gcm::aead::consts::U12> as aes_gcm::KeyInit>::new(&key.into());
    |                                       ^^^ not found in this scope
    |
help: you might be missing a type parameter
    |
103 |     fn test_aesgcm<Aes>() {
    |                   +++++
```

Using `U12` as the `TagSize` was trivial, as the default was `U16`.  Likewise, using `U12` as the `NonceSize` was obvious.

How do I find out what my options are for the value of the `Aes` type parameter?

I'm interested in a general answer for unknown type parameters, as well as the answer to this specific question.

Answer (score 1):

The specific answer is `Aes256` i.e. this works:

```
let cipher = <aes_gcm::AesGcm<Aes256, aes_gcm::aead::consts::U12, aes_gcm::aead::consts::U12> as aes_gcm::KeyInit>::new(&key.into());
```

I was confused by the alias being `pub type Aes256Gcm = AesGcm<Aes256, U12>;` - I had forgotten that their was a default for `TagSize`.  Therefore I could just copy the Aes256 from this alias.

I am still interested in how to solve this for unknown generic parameters.